# pass facebook response to flash callback external interface

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api

I've try to pass response of facebook api request that I get it via FB JS-SDK into my flash application using external interface but I don't get what response type, it result [object object] when I print it in console but when I try type such as response.name or .id or using scope (some value display correct but some still display [object object]).

So, 
First, what data type that returned by fb's response?
How I can pass it into flash apps, what about the type argument that I must set?
Then, which is the effective solution between extract the response each key that store it in an array then pass it into flash then extract again each part or send response object to flash then extract it in flash side?

I'm so confused because when I use JSON.decode method in js, it results nothing (undefined).
I'll appreciate for your attention and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use JSON.decode your facebook data, you already get a JSON object that is ready to work with. Though flash doesn't know what is to be there in your JSON object so there will be no code snippets (consider it as a dynamic object)
For example, when you get your simple information about user*FB.api('/me'...)*, you have a *.name* property:

```
...
public function receivedResponce(response:Object):void
{
    trace(responce.name);
}
...
```

You can get any other type of data returned by facebook request, whether it's a friend list or link to the user photo. 
There's a lot of information about what fields do facebook requests return, try reading it's [API guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)